# Error when running a script on jenkins that is installed in a docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to execute a script on jenkins that is installed in a docker.

My Docker-compose is :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
     -  /c/Users/cpaez/Documents/Automation/MOM/JSFiles:/usr/bin/docker
     -  $HOME/.jenkins/:/var/jenkins_home 
     -  /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

And my Dockerfile is :

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins
 
USER SYSTEM
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y maven
 
USER SYSTEM
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

When i try to execute a job executing shell command line the following :

./run.sh

I obtain :

```
Started by user Carolina 
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\cpaez\Documents\Automation\MOM\JSFiles
[JSFiles] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins7092419659009271524.sh
+ ./run.sh
/tmp/jenkins7092419659009271524.sh: 2: /tmp/jenkins7092419659009271524.sh: ./run.sh: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I changed my  workspace for C:\Users\cpaez\Documents\Automation\MOM\JSFiles   (where is my script) and also tried to assing the global variable PATH to = C:\Users\cpaez\Documents\Automation\MOM\JSFiles in Jenkins and obtained the same result.

Anyone can help me? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to execute a shell script on a windows system, and windows does not support executing of shell file.
Kindly try to execute the bat file

Or you can try this which i found online

Windows will not support shell scripts out of the box as per my knowledge. You can install Cygwin or Git for Windows, go to Manage Jenkins > Configure System Shell and point it to the location of sh.exe file found in their installation.

For example:
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe

https://discuss.devopscube.com/t/it-doesnt-recognize-shell-script-syntax/638